# Program not running in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am running an android application that simply pops out a window saying "hello." When I run it in the emulator, it says "Unfortunately, HelloAndroid has stopped." Is there an error in my code?

```
package com.example.helloandroid;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class HelloAndroid {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(200, 300);

    JLabel text = new JLabel();
    text.setText("Hello");
    text.setForeground(Color.RED);
    window.add(text);
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't think Android supports using Swing like that... I recommend following the [Android Hello World sample](https://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Comment: @Greg is correct - Android does __not__ support the full desktop Java API, and does not support Swing or (IIRC) awt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support the Swing/(IIRC) awt, or the full desktop Java API. Sorry.